# What is my favorite song?

Tags: cipher, pattern, music

I think this song is one of the greatest of all time, when it comes to lyrics. It starts like this:

`ELDR
 ESYL
 NSMOD
 FINIE
 OEOA
 WTYU
 KIHOA
 GI`

`HLOAK
 REDV
 CMTTL
 AN`

> What is my favorite song then?

---

This song is good too, but not as good as the one I'm asking about. It starts like this:

`IHTM
 HRES
 SAPNH
 EGTNE
 CSNA
 O
 IN`

`NGTIE
 IHES
 AHEST`

Or, in other words:

> Night time sharpens, heightens each sensation

Comment: It would've been a little bit harder if you excluded the second part with the solution, that pretty much gave it away (at least for me)

Comment: @LukasRotter, what about deleting second part of the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting the letters together, we get the lines

> Hello darkness, my old friend
>  I've come to talk with you again

from the song

> "The Sound of Silence" by Simon and Garfunkel.

I found this by first examining the second half of the question, whose answer was given:

> `IHTM` + **NGTIE** = **N**`I`**G**`H`**T**`T`**I**`M`**E**;
>  `HRES` + **SAPNH** = **S**`H`**A**`R`**P**`E`**N**`S`**H**;
>  `EGTNE` + **IHES** = `E`**I**`G`**H**`T`**E**`N`**S**`E`;
>  `CSNA` + **AHEST** = **A**`C`**H**`S`**E**`N`**S**`A`**T**;
>  `O` + **IN** = **I**`O`**N**.

Applying the same method to the ciphertext in the first half of the question, we find:

> `ELDR` + **HLOAK** = **H**`E`**L**`L`**O**`D`**A**`R`**K**;
>  `ESYL` + **NSMOD** = **N**`E`**S**`S`**M**`Y`**O**`L`**D**;
>  `FINIE` + **REDV** = `F`**R**`I`**E**`N`**D**`I`**V**`E`;
>  `OEOA` + **CMTTL** = **C**`O`**M**`E`**T**`O`**T**`A`**L**;
>  `WTYU` + **KIHOA** = **K**`W`**I**`T`**H**`Y`**O**`U`**A**;
>  `GI` + **AN** = `G`**A**`I`**N**.

Comment: @Bulldogg6404 Done.

Comment: @humn Huh, for some reason I thought it wouldn't work that way round. Fixed.